# xamarin forms remove spacing between grid.rows not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, spacing

In my Xamarin.Forms project I have a grid with 2 rows and 3 columns.
In row1 I have a label, in row2 I have a stackpanel vertical.
There seems to be a huge space between the label and the stackpanel, how do I remove this spacer?

I have tried using rowspacing=0 but it is not working.  any ideas?

if I remove the stackpanel and just use labels in different rows the space gets removed... but I want to keep the stackpanel

this is the code...

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" RowSpacing="0"
      Margin="5"
      BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backgroundColorWhite}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start"
           Margin="5,5,0,0"
           Text="{Binding MyUserSelections.SelectedClientName}" 
           TextColor="{StaticResource textColorBlack}"
           FontSize="16"
           FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                 Orientation="Vertical" 
                 Padding="0" 
                 Margin="5,0,0,5"
                 Spacing="0">
        <... elements .../>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                 Padding="0" 
                 Margin="0,0,0,5"
                 Spacing="0" 
                 Orientation="Vertical" 
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
        <... elements .../>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                 Padding="0" 
                 Margin="0,0,5,0"
                 Spacing="0" 
                 Orientation="Vertical" 
                 HorizontalOptions="End" >
        <... elements .../>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: ive added the code... trying to get a screenshot

Comment: found the issue... it was because I was defining both rows *... should have made size auto

Comment: Good you've noticed! I was already writing it. Posted to further references. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without the code:

The problem is that you have specified the same row height. That is why you have a big gap.
Change the Height values, they are the problem.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#Rows_and_Columns

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the doc... found the issue... it was because I was defining both rows *... should have made size auto. thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting both row definitions to `*`. It means each one will take a half of available space of the content. You should set the first on to `Auto` in order to use only the space needed to show the row content. The rest of space would be occupied by the second row.

I think you'll like to set `Grid.ColumnSpan="3"` to the first element too. It'll give more horizontal space to it.

Like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
      RowSpacing="0"
      Margin="5"
      BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backgroundColorWhite}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           HorizontalOptions="Start"
           Margin="5,5,0,0"
           Text="{Binding MyUserSelections.SelectedClientName}" 
           TextColor="{StaticResource textColorBlack}"
           FontSize="16"
           FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    (...)

</Grid>
```